# Not receiving "webViewLink" in response?

Tags: google-drive-api

After turning on Google Drive API access from the management console and getting my Client ID keys, I followed the sample code (using Python 2.7) and I am able to insert a folder, set the appropriate permissions (type=anyone,role=reader), and insert a text/html type file into the new folder.

However the JSON file resource objects I receive from executing insert on the drive service have no 'webViewLink' field! There are 'webContentLink' and 'selfLink' fields but 'webViewLink', which is necessary for static HTML publishing, seems to be missing.

Most perplexing. If this feature hasn't been turned on yet or if I need to configure my account settings to allow HTML publishing please let me know. Any other help would be most appreciated ;)

Comment: You can find answer to your question in [this thread][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664084/webviewlink-is-empty-null-when-using-php-code-sample/13667012#13667012

Answer (score 1):

The `webViewLink` property is only returned for public folders, and not the single files inside such folders. You can use that as the base url to construct links to your files.

Comment: Hello Claudio. I know this reply is too late, but `webViewLink ` seems to be a property of Filed class, which makes it seem like `webViewLink ` is actually linked to the specified file. (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) I'd appreiciate any insight.

Answer (score 1):

The **WebViewLink** file property can be retrieved by doing something like this:

```
$file = $service->files->get($file_id, array('fields' => 'webViewLink'));
$web_link_view = $file->getWebViewLink();
```

OR

```
$sheetsList = $drive_service->files->listFiles([
  'fields' => 'files(id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink)',
]);

$web_link_view = $sheetsList->current()->getWebViewLink();
```

Pay attention that you should load the file specifying which fields you wanna bring with it (In this case, `webViewLink`). If you don't do that, only `id` and `name` will be available.

If you also need to configure file permissions, you can do something like:

```
$permissions = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permissions->setRole('writer');
$permissions->setType('anyone');

$drive_service->permissions->create($file_id, $permissions);
```

Possible values for `setRole()` and `setType()` can be found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create