# 'webViewLink' is empty/null when using PHP code sample

Tags: google-apps, google-drive-api

Using the latest version of PHP apis from Google (0.60), the code sample from [google developer page](https://developers.google.com/drive/publish-site) seems to work except that the 'webViewLink' field is empty/null when using 'print_r($createdFile)' at the end of the function.

The drive.google.com site for my Google Apps domain shows the new folder successfully created with public permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Not receiving "webViewLink" in response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652364/not-receiving-webviewlink-in-response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, if you have folder ID, you can use https://googledrive.com/host/FOLDER_ID_HERE

Answer (score 4):

A "few" years later here's a working sample with a service account. I have a G Suite account and in https://admin.google.com/example.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:ManageOauthClients I have set my API client to API scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive and then

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('my_auth.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
$client->setSubject('admin.example.com');
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$x = $service->files->listFiles([
  'spaces' => 'drive', // this doesn't seem necessary
  'q' => 'name = "download"',
  'fields' => 'files(id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink)',
]);
```

Do pay attention to the `fields` argument: it does *not* retrieve anything but `id` and `name` if you leave it out.

Comment: For development you can use the special value * to return all fields, but you'll achieve greater performance by only selecting the fields you need... https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a small JavaScript app that lists your public folders. Can you confirm your folder is showing in the list? If it's not showing, it's not shared publicly and thus there's no webViewLink:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B0YvUuHHn3Mna3Rzb19tLTYyOXc/

the page is hosted in Google drive itself so it's being served by Google Drive and accessing Google Drive and for anyone that asks, no, the Universe did not implode :-)

Answer (score 1):

The **WebViewLink** file property can be retrieved by doing something like this:

```
$file = $service->files->get($file_id, array('fields' => 'webViewLink'));
$web_link_view = $file->getWebViewLink();
```

OR

```
$sheetsList = $drive_service->files->listFiles([
  'fields' => 'files(id, name, webViewLink, webContentLink)',
]);

$web_link_view = $sheetsList->current()->getWebViewLink();
```

As @chx mentioned, you should load the file specifying which fields you wanna bring with it (In this case, `webViewLink`). If you don't do that, only `id` and `name` will be available.

If you also need to configure file permissions, you can do something like:

```
$permissions = new \Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$permissions->setRole('writer');
$permissions->setType('anyone');

$drive_service->permissions->create($file_id, $permissions);
```

Possible values for `setRole()` and `setType()` can be found here: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create