# Google Drive API: How to get a sharable link to Google docs? (alternateLink, webViewLink return null)

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I referred to [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664084/webviewlink-is-empty-null-when-using-php-code-sample) and [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652364/not-receiving-webviewlink-in-response), still clueless as to how to get a link to a `Google Doc`.

[According to the offical document,](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource)  `webViewLink` is "A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser". However, it doesn't return anything but `null`, while other properties, such as id or mimeType, return expected values. (`webContentLink` returns `null` too.)

I could simply use this URL, `https://drive.google.com/open?FILE_ID_HERE`, but I'm not sure this works in other people's browser.

I'd appreciate any advice!

Comment: Please share your code so that it will be easier to pinpoint the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the file ID of a Google Document, you can use the following URL to access the file in the browser.

```
https://drive.google.com/open?id=FILE_ID
```

The link will be accessible to anyone with whom you have shared the file.