# How to get url to google drive file from GTLDriveFile?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, google-drive-api

In old version of the Google Drive API v2 a [fileresource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource-representations) contained was `alternateUrl` which could be used to point to the file in browser. In latest version of Google Drive v3 a [fileresource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations) contains only `webViewLink`, but it's returned `nil`.

Maybe there is way to convert file identifier to url ?

Edit:
As mentioned in similar question on stack overflow, the webViewLink is returned only for public folders. As a workaround i used for now:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://drive.google.com/file/d/%@/view", file.identifier]
```

But not sure if this urls will be valid in future, perfectly google api would return something i could use to later open file in browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Not receiving "webViewLink" in response?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652364/not-receiving-webviewlink-in-response)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in my app, my webViewLink have value!
You must in query action add following code`fileListQuery.fields = @"*";`