# How to download pdf from google drive V3 API in IOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

Working with the `Google Drive V3 API` to download files and pdf.

1. As per Google Doc, Google Drive V3 Api below is the Url to download files(say text file).

   `NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?alt=media",file.identifier];`

However when i simply used this url, it gives me error while downloading files then i tried something like this with Client ID and its working fine.(here i removed alt=media and added client id in the url.Which is perfectly working fine).Below is the modified url.

```
`NSString *url = [NSStringstringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@?key=%@", file.identifier,kClientID];`
```

2. Now for pdf they have mentioned in the Google Doc to use the below url.

   `NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@/export?alt=media&mimeType=application/pdf", file.identifier];`

Again i m facing the same problem..the above url for downloading the pdf giving me the error.i have done all the permutation and combination with the url with no success.

***The Sample code provided in the Doc is using google drive V2 Api.

So,How to download pdf with the use of Google Drive V3 Api?Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Today, I success for download file from Google Drive V3 Api.

```
self.fileSize = [loadFile.quotaBytesUsed unsignedIntegerValue];

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [GTMSessionFetcher fetcherWithURLString:loadFile.webContentLink];
        if(fetcher==nil)
        {
            break;
        }

        fetcher.authorizer             = [GTLServiceDrive sharedServiceDrive].authorizer;
        fetcher.destinationFileURL     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.intoPath];

        __block typeof(self) blockSelf = self;
        fetcher.downloadProgressBlock  = ^(int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            //get download progress
        };

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        [fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(fetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
```

Comment: This also can show progress in my view. If also have another problem you can let me known. thx.

Comment: @ Andrew Lai, sharedServiceDrive Instance Method is not in the Api.Where you got this?

Comment: GTLDriveFile *file=[dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
   NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@/export?alt=media&mimeType=application/pdf",
                          file.identifier] 
    GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [self.service.fetcherService fetcherWithURLString:url];
    [fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData data, NSError error) {
        if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Retrieved file content");
            // File Downloaded!
               }];

Comment: @samar, By using GTLServiceDrive and set following two property.
shouldFetchNextPages = YES, authorizer set by GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch's method authForGoogleFromKeychainForName:clientID:clientSecret:

Comment: i m always getting loadFile.webContentLink nil.

Comment: Have you checked my Code? i mean                                           GTLDriveFile *file=[dataArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];               NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@/export?alt=media&mimeType=application/pdf",
                          file.identifier];  This url is from google doc.i think the whole problem is in url formation.please help.

Comment: ,.,Hi..Can you send me any working demo to download pdf form Google Drive V3 Api.Thanks in advance.

Comment: you must use file.webContentLink substitution NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/%@/…;, file.identifier];

Comment: This link also contain file.identifier and keyword "export"...from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file

Comment: i always get file.identifier value but for file.webContentLink..its give me nil.if you have any working demo please send it to me..so that i get to know where i m making mistake.Meanwhile some says that its a bug in Google.i m not sure.

Comment: and there is no such method [sharedServiceDrive]  in GTLServiceDrive class.

Comment: This can help you to get webContentLink Value.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37315438/how-to-get-url-to-google-drive-file-from-gtldrivefile/37343476#37343476

Comment: method [sharedServiceDrive] is my serviceDrive "Singleton" method

Comment: ..Thanks a lot for the help.Finally after so long its Working and in between i found another way to do it.The webContentLink was the main culprit.Anyway thanks once again.

Comment: another way?Can you share with me ?

Comment: Yup...i mean the code u have provided is one way.,and the other way is the url provide by the doc..After modifying it slightly both the url mention in the doc is working properly(this only happens if you set the correct webContentLink property.).

Comment: Again getting the same error.Andrew can you send me the zip file of working demo on my email id its (samar.bravo11@gmail.com).So that i can check what mistake i have made.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

-(void)downloadFile:(NSString *)url{

```
GTMSessionFetcher *fetcher = [GTMSessionFetcher fetcherWithURLString:url];
fetcher.authorizer             = [[GTLServiceDrive alloc]init].authorizer;
fetcher.destinationFileURL     = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:url];

__block typeof(self) blockSelf = self;
fetcher.downloadProgressBlock  = ^(int64_t bytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesWritten, int64_t totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
    //get download progress
    NSLog(@"bytesWritten = %d",bytesWritten);
     NSLog(@"totalBytesWritten = %d",totalBytesWritten);
     NSLog(@"totalBytesExpectedToWrite = %d",totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

};

[fetcher beginFetchWithDelegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(fetcher:finishedWithData:error:)];
```

}

Comment: I call this method in "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and url is "file.webContentLink". When I run my code, error "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=518 "The file “docs.google.com” couldn’t be saved because URL type https isn’t supported." UserInfo={NSURL=https:/docs.google.com/}"

Comment: I've read all your source code. You must set destinationFileURL with local file path url, not same to fetcherWithURLString's url. I also reply your mail.