# Download files from google drive with the latest SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, download, google-drive-api, filelist

I prefer iOS (Objective-C) code but the question is linked with google drive API. So a solution in any other programming language may belong here.

My previous code:

```
GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
query.q = ...;
... //send query and get links to files
```

But it was correct in Google Drive API v2 only - query returned a list of `GTLDriveFile` objects and `GTLDriveFile` contained field `downloadUrl`.

But Google Drive API v3 doesn't have such field and according to [this document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/migration#fields) I should perform additional request with `queryForFilesGetWithFileId:` and link 2 results between themselves, shouldn't I? How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

downloadUrl has been removed. If you want download file, i have tried successfully!
[How to download pdf from google drive V3 API in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37339785/how-to-download-pdf-from-google-drive-v3-api-in-ios/37342946#37342946)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to [Download Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#downloading_a_file), you'll use one of the given URLs below, depending on the type of download that you'd like to perform.

- Download a file — `files.get` with `alt=media` file resource
- Download and export a Google Doc — `files.export`
- Link a user to a file — `webContentLink` from the file resource

For example, to download a file using `alt=media`, you make an authorized HTTP `GET` request to the file's resource URL and include the query parameter alt=media. Using the sample request format:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/0B9jNhSvVjoIVM3dKcGRKRmVIOVU?alt=media
Authorization: Bearer ya29.AHESVbXTUv5mHMo3RYfmS1YJonjzzdTOFZwvyOAUVhrs
```

As stated, your app must be authorized with a scope that allows reading of file content. And, an app using the `drive.readonly.metadata` scope would not be authorized to download the file contents. Users with edit permission may restrict downloading by read-only users by setting the `viewersCanCopyContent` field to true.

Please check through the documentation for the detailed instructions for performing the given types of downloads.